# Analytic method for determining if a function will be negative.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am learning the alternating series test and one of the conditions is that the function must be decreasing. One way to figure this out is to take the derivative and asses whether it is less than 0. For example :

$ \sum_{i=2}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\ln(n)}{n} \\
\text{i. Prove that the series is descending.} \\
f(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \\\\
 f\prime(x) = \frac{1 -\ln{x}}{x^2} < 0 \\
\text{Apply the derivative to see if its < 0, because this particular problem is fairly simple I can see that} \\
f\prime(x) < 0 \text{ for all x > e.} \\
\text{The main point of my question is what happens if the derivative is very difficult to determine whether it will be positive or negative.} \\
$

Is there a better more rigid way of finding out if a function is positve or negative ?

Comment: Do you mean to say is there a more rigid way of checking if a function is decreasing or increasing? As in the derivative is less that zero or the actual function is less than zero

Comment: Checking if the function is decreasing by taking the derivative as shown in the example above.

Comment: Well maybe in some cases, you could show that $f(b) < f(a)$ for $b > a$ and show it is decreasing that way. This would require you to prove $\frac{f(b)}{f(a)} <1$ and may result in a more complex equation than the derivative itself.